# Please correct this code Read a text file in dropbox using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code. The purpose of this code is to read a text file in the drop box using vb.net.

```
Option Strict Off
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Net
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim ABC As String
Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim file As New
System.IO.StreamReader(myWebClient.OpenRead("https://www.dropbox.com  
/s/82wlkg6l4idkewk/KPRAVEENSTOCKS.txt?dl=0"))
ABC = file.ReadToEnd
MsgBox(ABC)
file.Close()
Me.Close()
End Sub 
End Class
```

But I got the Msgbox string as some programming codes, not my text in the text file.

Sorry for my bad English.

I have tried a lot of times, and searched the net for solution, but I am not able to get it. I request that you solve this problem.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]  ...and set Option Strict ON

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL you are accessing (from `www.dropbox.com` to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`):

```
System.IO.StreamReader(myWebClient.OpenRead("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/82wlkg6l4idkewk/KPRAVEENSTOCKS.txt"))
```

If you access the file through `www.dropbox.com` then you will get the Dropbox HTML wrapper around the file you are trying to access.

OR

Specify, `dl=1` rather than `dl=0` in your URL.

```
System.IO.StreamReader(myWebClient.OpenRead("https://www.dropbox.com/s/82wlkg6l4idkewk/KPRAVEENSTOCKS.txt?dl=1"))
```